# Error converting varchar to numeric with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Query

```
SELECT TOP 1000
CASE WHEN VRI.Square_Footage <> '' 
THEN VRI.Square_Footage 
ELSE 
    CASE WHEN VRI.Property_Type = 'LAND' 
        THEN CAST((CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 3),VRI.Acres)*43560) AS DECIMAL) 
    ELSE 
        VRI.Lot_Size 
    END 
END
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables AS VRI
```

Even if I checked for `VRI.Acres` with `isnumeric()`, it still yield the same exact error? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Thanks for the edit! Btw, you have a very cool avatar ;)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISNUMERIC` doesn't guarantee that it will successfully cast to `decimal`.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('£100') /*Returns 1*/

SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 3),'£100') /*Error*/
```

Additionally all branches of the `case` statement need to return compatible datatypes. It looks like `VRI.Square_Footage` is a string.

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 CASE
                  WHEN ISNUMERIC(VRI.Square_Footage + 'e0') = 1 THEN
                  VRI.Square_Footage
                  WHEN VRI.Property_Type = 'LAND'
                       AND ISNUMERIC(VRI.Acres + 'e0') = 1 THEN CAST((
                  CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 3), VRI.Acres) * 43560 ) AS DECIMAL)
                  WHEN ISNUMERIC(VRI.Lot_Size + 'e0') = 1 THEN VRI.Lot_Size
                END
FROM   View_Report_Information_Tables AS VRI
```

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. Yes, `VRI.Square_Footage` is actually `varchar`. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: This. You can't mix strings and numbers in the same column.  One of them must be converted to the other.

Comment: @Jerry Ritcey: So that means I have to convert all `varchar` to decimal?

Comment: @Chan - The only way of mixing (non numeric) strings and numbers would be a cast to `sql_variant` or cast the numbers as strings. Can you provide an example of the data that fails?

Comment: @Martin: I believe it failed when data = '' because `VRI.Square_Footage` can be `''` when `VRI.Acres = ''`.

Comment: Do your `Square_Footage` and `Acres` columns only contain numbers (as strings) and `''`? (And if so why not change the data type?)

Comment: @Martin: Sorry I did not write this sql query, someone did. I worked on a report, and figure out the bug came from this query. By change data type, did you mean convert all of them to numeric? or change their original data type to numeric?

Comment: @Chan wouldn't `NULL` (which is compatible with decimal values) be  a better representation than `''`

Comment: @Conrad Frix: I would agree with you. Unfortunately, this belongs to SQL team, I'm not in charge of it. Btw, I just converted it back to `varchar` and the sql query run fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here run this

```
 SELECT ISNUMERIC('d25')
```

That can be converted to float but not decimal/numeric

```
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,'2d5')
```

As you can see, you can't depend on numeric for decimal/numeric data types

Take a look at [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber) for some code that will show you how you can check